# Why do Java classes like java.net.InetAddress not log anything?

Tags: java, logging

Is there a particular reason why classes like
java.net.InetAddress do not log a single line?

For certain situations it might become quite handy to have some debug information from Java library classes.

Comment: [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)?

Comment: Hmm, weak argument, isn't it? All classes' primary purpose is not to log. They do anyway in order to help their users to gain insights.

Comment: Is there a specific situation that you have in mind? It could potentially log hundreds of lines, so...what *should* it log in your opinion? Since logging isn't free, it's problematic. Also the OS logs network things, so it might not be very useful to have double bookkeeping anyway.

Comment: I would like to know if the ip address of a hostname is taken from the cache or by querying the dns server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There are many log frameworks out there. Java tried to add its own, but by then it was too late, and java's built in logging is a distant also-ran. Which gets us back to: What should it use? `java.util.log`, except few use that? slf4j? It's not universal and it would be a little bizarre, given that j.u.log exists. Yet another meta-layer?
2. What would you want INetAddress to log? Creation? If you want to log the creation of some specific class, there are other tools for that, there's no need to litter log stuff into the code. Such generalized tools (a general tool that can log the creation of some specific type or the invocation of some specific method, anytime and everytime it is done) would, in one fell swoop, give you the ability to log what you need, for all the core classes, and any other class/method from any other library that doesn't log things the way you want.
3. logging is decidedly not free. Opening a file to write data is in fact incredibly expensive, and a lot of the core libraries have to be written ignoring knuth's maxim (Premature optimization is the root of all evil - trite and oversimplified, but a popular saying) – because all sorts of code uses core libraries, so they have to be microoptimized to some extent. Logging frameworks become a lot faster if by default they don't actually end up logging (due to e.g. a *level* setting), but you're still on the hook for doing a lookup to check if you should be logging a thing.

More generally logging seems out of place for most of the core library stack: Logs are best used to raise important events (and the core lib has no idea what is important, it is almost by definition not 'end point' code), and to track the flow of a process, but most core libs do a single task, which means 'log it' boils down to 'log method invocations' which gets us back to #2: You can do that, you don't need java core code to explicitly have log lines included.

Comment: 1) As Java has it's own logging library this would be the one I would prefer. It's never too late to add log messages. 2) Log if the resolved up is taken from the cache for instance. 3) Right, but checking a boolean condition is not that expensive.

Comment: It should be noted that InetAddress existed way before JUL. For the reasons given in 3) it may have been too risky to change the implementation and performance of such a low level class in later versions.

Comment: @Oliver so, you think the fact that ~80%+ of the community would then be left in the cold doesn't matter? That's.. an opinion. There's some wisdom in choosing j.u.l. Surely you understand that it is tricky and therefore not a slamdunk at all? There are far more useful things to spend time on. Your ideas about how it's not expensive are, in light of the performance needs of core libs, mistaken.